# Windmill-Without web browser

Tags: python, selenium, windmill, browser-testing

In selenium testing, there is htmlunitdriver which you can run tests without browser with. I need to do this with windmill too. Is there a way to do this in windmill?

Thank!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to run Windmill in headless mode (no monitor) you can do it by running

Xvfb :99 -ac &

DISPLAY=:99 windmill firefox -e test=/path/to/your/test.py

Comment: While the commands do not give any errors on OS X, it does not work, safari is still running as normal. I gues this will not work on OS X for any browser.